# how to extract bz2 files in command line of fedora system?

Tags: bash, extract, fedora, bzip2

I just find tar, unzip, bunzip2, 7z, unrar, gunzip, all do not work for bz2 files.
Is there a simple method to do that?
Or where can I download a rpm file to install?

Comment: Not programming related, belongs on SuperUser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bunzip2` should work flawlessly, as should the `-j` option to `tar`. If they don't, you're doing something wrong, and should post the command line plus the error message.

If in doubt, run `file` on the archive to make sure it actually *is* compressed in bz2 format (and not just named like that).

Comment: +1 for suggestion about `file` command. If `bunzip2` is failing, quite possibly the archive is corrupt or not a `bzip2` archive.